# Remover post-type Artigos Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

### Remover

Gostaria de remover o post-type Artigos do menu do Wordpress pesquisei algumas possibilidades mas nada surtiu efeito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei criando o método `unregister_post_type` desta forma:

```
function unregister_post_type( $post_type ) {
    global $wp_post_types;
    if ( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type ] ) ) {
        unset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type ] );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar **action** para uma função ser aceita pelo core do wordpress. Não esqueça de por no **functions.php**

```
function post_remove ()      //criando a função post_remove para remover o  menu item
{ 
   remove_menu_page('edit.php');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'post_remove');   //adicionando action
```

**Fonte:** http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-remove-menus-from-the-wordpress-dashboard/

Comment: Que bom que ajudou, man.

Answer (score 1):

O post_type artigos na verdade se refere ao post_type padrão "posts" do WordPress. Acho muito difícil que você consiga "desregistrá-lo" e sair impune, até porque eles são a base sobre a qual todo o sistema foi criado. Provavelmente o céu vai cair na sua cabeça e um buraco se abrirá no chão...(brincadeira...)

Se você quer remover o menu existe uma forma bem mais simples de fazer isso que é, bem, remover o menu:

`remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );`

Pronto! O menu se foi e o céu continua no lugar...